# Showing only limited text in HTML ui using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

Hi I am getting List of multiple records like these from webservice.

1. `cn=HOUW-MAR-LVL1,cn=Chola MS Organization structure,cn=cordys,cn=devInst2,o=chol`
2. `cn=SUW-COM-NONMOT-LVL1-TN1,cn=Chola MS Organization Structure,cn=cordys,cn=devInst2,o=cholamandalamins.com`

I want to show only `HOUW-MAR-LVL1` or `SUW-COM-NONMOT-LVL1-TN1` i.e. text between first `=` and `,`.

Is there any possibility to handle that in HTML or angularJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format is always xx=, then you can just use regular JavaScript string/array methods to get what you require.

```
var originalString = "cn=HOUW-MAR-LVL1,cn=Chola MS Organization structure,cn=cordys,cn=devInst2,o=chol"

//First split the string at each comma
var arrayOfStrings = originalString.split(",") 

//Now use map to go through the array one string at a time
var trimmedStrings = arrayOfStrings.map(function(stringToTrim) {
//Trim the characters up to and including the equals sign
    return stringToTrim.substring((stringToTrim.indexOf("=") + 1 ), stringToTrim.length);
});

//Result = trimmedStrings

["HOUW-MAR-LVL1","Chola MS Organization structure","cordys","devInst2","chol"]
```

Each individual trimmed string can be accessed by its index number